# How do I add angular to an express.js page?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, mean-stack

I've created a Meanstack project and I cant figure out how to add the AngularJS files from the npm package into the page...

Am I supposed to manually find the files and add them the old fasioned way in a ?

If not where and how do I add it?

Screenshot is for clarification on my position.

[Screenshot of solution explorer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wLBx2.png)

Comment: Did you see any of the yeoman-generated projects?

Comment: Not specifically, I'm completely new to js development other than some angular, so I probably have but not understood them.

Comment: Oh, ok, then better to try things manually first.when you learn what is it that needs to be done, you can start using automaton tools. It would be smart to know what a tool does and why before you use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, as I can see from your screenshot you have installed the bower-module. You should probably consider using bower for downloading/installing client-side scripts instead of npm, and use npm for server-side scripts. It's a common practice to do it that way. You can easily learn it [here](http://bower.io/).

To answer your question regarding the AngularJS-files. Yes, you will have to add them manually. What I usually do is setting up a grunt-rutine to concatenate all files of my own angular implementation into a single file. In that way you will only have to add the script once to your index-file. You can set up grunt to run every time you save a file, and then automatically concatenates the files for you.